# Как исправить некорректное отображение русских символов в FreePascal?

Tags: freepascal

Начал работать в текстовыми файлами в FPC 2.2.4, но случилась проблема. Он не корректно пишет русские буквы в файл, хотя со всем остальным проблем нет (английские буквы, числа).

Что делать? Я использую Windows XP SP3. Мне нужна именно эта версия паскаля, так как в будущем хочу попробовать написать программу для kolibrios (ради интереса).
Вопрос уже решён. Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Покажите минимальный пример вашего кода и результата, пожалуйста

Comment: `var f:Text;
begin
        Assign(f, 'D:\se.txt');
        Rewrite(f);
        writeln(F,'Привет, мир!');
        close(f);
end.`  Результат: ЏаЁўҐв, ¬Ёа!

Comment: пишет нормально, но ваш редактор кодировку не понимает. попробуйте в utf8 писать: https://wiki.freepascal.org/UTF-8

Comment: добавлю. у меня прямо руки чешутся, когда это вижу, нажать в фаре f8 и сменить кодировку c win1251 на ibm866

Comment: Под вопросом кнопка "править", воспользуйтесь ей

Comment: Извините, не совсем понимаю как сменить кодировку в IDE.

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо всем огромное.